# Page Loading Time for All Content

Tags: php, performance, pageload, pagespeed, page-load-time

I have searched about page loading time than I found a solution about it. It is working, there is not any problem. But I have a question about that.

Is below code only measures php's execution time or all page(html,images,css,js etc)?

```
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$start = $time;
```

...
php, html, javascript, images, videos etc
...

...

```
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo $total_time;
```

If this type of solutions for only execution time of php, How can I learn all page's page load time?

Comment: I hope its only for script execution...

Comment: Only execution time, you can echo the microtime on the webpage, then calculate when the document is ready with javascript to calculate the full execution time.

Comment: firebug will show you the page load time on the network tab. Or in chrome the developer tools netwrok tab.

Comment: I will suggest to listen for the `window.load` event in this case. or check network panel of your browser to get more details

Answer (score 0):

This only the execution time of the PHP. For detailed results for other assets try Google PageSpeed Insights or equivalent.

Comment: But I want to print out time to my pages everytime

Comment: Then you will need some vague Javascript function that will inaccurately calculate that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine how long a page takes to load in the browser, look at the navigation timing API https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html

It's supported in all modern browsers with the exception of Safari

You can also use the Resource Timing API to dig deeper in Chrome and IE 10